# Spree 2.3 and Payflow Pro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, spree, activemerchant, payflowpro

I am migrating a client's site from an antiquated Joomla-with-virtue-mart store to Spree (2.3.1, Rails 4.1.8)

They are using Payflow Pro on their current site. I see that there is a gateway in Spree for Payflow Pro (Spree::Gateway::PayflowPro) but there is an incongruity between the fields that are presented in spree to provide credentials and what appear to be required. Specifically; payflow pro appears to require a Merchant Login, a User Name, and a password. Spree only presents me with user name and password fields.

I am wondering if any of you have had any similar experiences setting up spree with this particular gateway and if so, would be willing to share some of your knowledge and experience with me here. There are a few spree-payflow gems floating around on github, but they are all very old and do not work with the current version of spree. Before I get started with all the forking and refactoring business, I thought I would plumb the stacks to see what anyone else has to say about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have got this working with a test sandbox on Paypal. The one thing I am still trying to sort out is how to set the Partner value. It defaults to Paypal, but there doesn't seem to be any place to override this in spree. This issue: https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway/pull/185 discusses the situation in depth, but does not provide an answer.

Comment: Ok Solved this one. The 2-3-stable branch did not have the partner preference set. After forking the repo and backporting that change, the partner field appears in the payment method configuration area in spree.